# String concatenation and comparison gives unexpected result in println statement

Tags: java, string, operator-precedence

I couldn't figure out the following behaviour,

```
String str1= "abc";
String str2 = "abc";

System.out.println("str1==str2 "+ str1==str2);
System.out.println("str1==str2 " + (str1==str2))
```

Output for the above statement is as follows:

> false
>
> str1==str2 true

Why is this happening? Why the output is not like follows:

> str1==str2 true
>
> str1==str2 true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`+` has higher precedence than `==`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).
So your code :

```
System.out.println("str1==str2 " + str1 == str2);
```

will effectively be

```
System.out.println(("str1==str2 "+str1) == str2);
```

so, you get `false`.

In case-2

```
System.out.println("str1==str2 " + (str1==str2));
```

you have used braces explicitly to compare `str1` with `str2` (which is `true`) and then append the value.

Comment: @OP also for more information related to **Operator Precedence**, please refer this java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed to println is evaluated left to right.

Therefore `"str1==str2 "+ str1` concatenates two Strings, which are later compared to `str2` and return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of operator precedence.

In the first statement the `+` operator is executed before the `==` and "str1==str2 " is appended to `str1`, after which the result of the appending is compared with `==` to `str2`.

In the second statement the brackets `()` denote the atomic pieces that should be evaluated before the top-level operators (i.e. the `+`) take place. This is why first `str1` is compared to `str2` with `==`, and then the result (`true`) is appended as a String to the `"str1==str2 "`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("str1==str2 "+ str1==str2);
```

in the above line, compiler checks  if

"str1==str2"+str1

that is  >>> "str1==str2 str1"  is equal to str2 or not

> That's why it prints it as false

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two String should always be done with the `equals` method. otherwise you compare if it is the same reference, not the same value!